# Morphological analysis of 'unlawfulness'

Tags: suffixes, linguistics

How would you give the internal structure of the word 'unlawfulness'? 

My attempt:
un - law - ful - ness
prefix - noun - suffix - suffix

Internal structure:
law + ful > Adjective
un + law + ful > Adjective
un + law + ful + ness > Noun

Will that be correct? Should I split 'lawful' into 'law + ful' so there's four morphemes in the word or keep it as three morphemes? If 'lawful' is split, then is the -ful counted as a suffix or an infix?

Answer (score 1):

For one, *-ful* cannot be an infix here, because it needs to be there **before** *-ness* can be (further) suffixed.

The rest, with four components, seems perfect.